# Bash script seems to be skipping lines

Tags: bash

I'm trying to put together a small script that sets up a "minimal" config on a new machine via `yadm`. I'm trying to call it like this:

```bash
curl -sS https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ferdinandyb/dotfiles/master/.config/yadm/minimalbootstrap | bash
```

And here's the script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "\033[1mrunning minimal bootstrap\033[0m"

mkdir -p ~/.local/bin

echo -e "\033[1msetting up yadm with local.class minimal\033[0m"
curl -fLo ~/.local/bin/yadm https://github.com/TheLocehiliosan/yadm/raw/master/yadm && chmod a+x ~/.local/bin/yadm
~/.local/bin/yadm clone https://github.com/ferdinandyb/dotfiles.git
~/.local/bin/yadm config --add local.class minimal
~/.local/bin/yadm sparse-checkout reapply

echo -e "\033[1minstalling fzf\033[0m"
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.git ~/.fzf
~/.fzf/install

echo -e "\033[1minstalling zoxide\033[0m"
curl -sS https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ajeetdsouza/zoxide/main/install.sh | bash

echo -e "\033[1minstalling vim plugins\033[0m"
vim +PlugUpdate +qall

echo -e "\033[1mchange default shell to zsh\033[0m"
chsh -s $(which zsh)
```

The thing is, the line trying to install zoxide and the vim plugins are never executed (while I always see the last echo with the default shell). If the `yadm` clone fails, due to the repo already being present the rest of the yadm lines also seem not to execute. Why is this not working as expected?

**edit:**

I ran the script with `curl [stuff] | bash -x`, here are all the output lines starting with `+`:

```
+ echo -e '\033[1mrunning minimal bootstrap\033[0m'
+ mkdir -p /root/.local/bin
+ echo -e '\033[1msetting up yadm with local.class minimal\033[0m'
+ curl -fLo /root/.local/bin/yadm https://github.com/TheLocehiliosan/yadm/raw/master/yadm
+ chmod a+x /root/.local/bin/yadm
+ /root/.local/bin/yadm clone https://github.com/ferdinandyb/dotfiles.git
+ /root/.local/bin/yadm config --add local.class minimal
+ /root/.local/bin/yadm sparse-checkout reapply
+ echo -e '\033[1minstalling fzf\033[0m'
+ git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.git /root/.fzf
+ /root/.fzf/install
+ echo -e '\033[1mchange default shell to zsh\033[0m'
++ which zsh
+ chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh
```

I tried changing up the order of execution by putting the fzf installer at the end, but now that does not execute after updating the vim plugins.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: `curl ... | bash -x` the `-x` turns on trace-level logging.

Comment: It still seems like line are just skipped.

Comment: I agree. Means something you're running is consuming stdin before it gets to bash, probably the fzf install script.

Comment: Switch to `bash <(curl ...)` instead of `curl ... | bash` and you'll moot that.

Comment: Or, if you're the author of the script, you can add `</dev/null` to the faulty lines (f/e, `~/.fzf/install </dev/null`) to prevent it.

Comment: Or, much saner, _don't do any of this at all_. With my security hat on (and the grumpy-old-man belt and suspenders), [`curl | bash` is a plague](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/213499/56587) and nobody should have even thought it was remotely acceptable in the first place.

Comment: As someone who has spent too much time looking at mangled escape sequences in text files, I beg you to stop trying to colorize your output like this.  At the absolute least, conditionally define variables like $RED and $YELLOW and make them blank when appropriate.  And read https://www.theregister.com/2023/08/09/ansi_escape_sequence_risks/

Comment: This question is getting to be several levels of TIL for me :)

Comment: @WilliamPursell Mangled logs are a good point, although I was planning to run this manually so it's just me reading it. But I'll probably forget about this and log it somewhere sometimes so I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I read your other answer about curlbash. What I get from that is that it would be safer to first curl the script, check that it's what I actually wrote and then execute it. But how much safer it the git clone I'm also doing? My feeling is, that I'm relying on the server hosting my repo to give me the correct files over http, so if curl | bash is compromised, then the entire repo could be too. Or does git save me here with the commit hashes?

Comment: Nix (except in scenarios where its security features are turned off) only allows network access during build when it knows what it's downloading ahead of time. There's a `fetchGit` builtin that sorta relaxes that, but in pure mode (as opposed to impure mode) it requires you to specify a distinct committish. Downloading a file in one step and running it in another is a _little_ safer than running a pipeline, but there's a reason it's not what I'm endorsing in my answer on the linked question.

Comment: Hmm, I think I'll just do a separate question about this over on security.

Comment: Roughly, if you want git committishes to save you, you need to _actually refer to trusted, vetted committishes_; referring to `master` or implicitly to `HEAD` means anyone who gets commit can change what you're going to run. Nix _forces_ you to decide on specific committishes (or tags that refer to them) since in pure mode it'll refuse to evaluate code that doesn't pin down a specific references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of feeding script text to bash on stdin (which can be disrupted by something else in the script *also* reading from stdin, thus consuming content intended for the interpreter), use process substitution:

```
bash <(curl -sS https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ferdinandyb/dotfiles/master/.config/yadm/minimalbootstrap)
```

In this particular case, it's almost certainly the fzf install script consuming content from stdin, which is thereafter unavailable to bash.

Comment: But would this explain the fact that for instance the echo of _minstalling zoxide_  can't be seen after the fzf install, but the echo of _change default shell to zsh_ a few lines further down *can* be seen in the trace? After all, the trace goes to stderr, and stderr is not consumed anywhere, so it should be visible completely.

Comment: @user1934428, it's _the echo command itself_ (on stdin via the pipe from curl) that gets eaten, not the output of running the command. If the code that would run the command isn't left on stdin, then of course the command isn't run at all, so no xtrace ever happens.

Answer (score 2):

A quick hack for this and similar situations, such as when copy-pasting several commands into a shell, is to wrap the entire script in a command group `{ ..; }`:

```
#!/bin/bash
{
your script here
}
```

The script will not start executing until the entire command group has been read. This avoids the problem of the commands competing with the shell for stdin, and avoids running any commands unless they're all successfully read.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> vim +PlugUpdate +qall
> ```

Vim is a full-blown *terminal* application. It doesn't like being run without a terminal, and PlugUpdate spawns a separate buffer to write its output and *modify* it. You *will* get funny output.

If you want to see the fun wall of text of escape sequences, you can `vim +PlugUpdate +qall 2>&1 | cat -v`

Comment: That _was_ pretty :)